# React.js - react-player how to play local video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I am currently trying to play a video on local host in react.js. I am using the react-player module to create a video player component. I am able to play videos using urls such as youtube and facebook links but I am unable to use local videos using the filepath. I read through all of the documentation on github for the module but I was unable to find an answer, which is why I am here asking you this question.
Below is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'



class Video extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div className='player-wrapper'>
          <ReactPlayer
            className='react-player fixed-bottom'
            url= 'M_03292018202006_00000000U2940605_1_001-1.MP4'
            width='100%'
            height='100%'
            controls = {true}

          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Video;
```

Answer (score 23):

With a [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) (short CRA) you could place your video files in the public folder e.g. in a subfolder `videos`. Then you can access that static file as you did it in your code.
[image]

CRA will just copy the files to the final static page as mentioned in the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

If you don't use a CRA setup you need to copy your video to the final bundle e.g. by using Webpack.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

class Video extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
        <div className='player-wrapper'>
            <ReactPlayer
            className='react-player fixed-bottom'
            url= 'videos/demo_video.MP4'
            width='100%'
            height='100%'
            controls = {true}

            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 19):

you have to create video object URL.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

 const [videoFilePath, setVideoFilePath] = useState(null);


const handleVideoUpload = (event) => {
setVideoFilePath(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
};
```

....

```
<input type="file" onChange={handleVideoUpload} />
```

...

```
<ReactPlayer url={videoFilePath} width="100%" height="100%" controls={true} />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Hello how can I play video from a spesific folder path  for example "E:\\video\\x.mp4" ? I don't want to upload

Answer (score 9):

**Main Catch**: All the statics should placed inside the **public folder**.
Any video, audio, images, etc.

**Why?**
Public folder will **not** be processed by Web-pack and hence remains untouched and you could see it as it is.
Placing it anywhere else would be processed and tweaked and optimised by webpacks, thus may change the compression, or extensions of video file that result in unproper parsing of code (though it is not seen with images, videos get affected by it).

**How to access public folder from code?**
Every file url is pointed to public folder. Every file url with `./` is pointed to file directory.
To access `public/video1.mp4` just write `url='video1.mp4'`.

eg.

```js
            <ReactPlayer playing url='video1.mp4'
                height='500px'
                width='800px'
                controls='true'
            />
```

Answer (score 6):

You would need to import the local video file to you component.

````
import myVideo from '../media/M_03292018202006_00000000U2940605_1_001-1.MP4'

class Video extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
          url={myVideo}
          // ...
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

```
````

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I tried importing it like you said just now but it when run using npm start it is just giving me a black background. Would you know why this is ?

Comment: My import link was just an example, so you need to import your file from it's location in your folder.

Comment: If it doesn't work, there may be a problem with the mp4 format. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6822 (assuming you are using Create React App)

Comment: @NinaW How to store multiple url in usestate which i got from api response??

Comment: @HariprasathLakshmanan, I usually use useEffect to fetch data from api and then useState to make it available (check this link: https://medium.com/geekculture/simple-data-fetching-in-react-with-the-fetch-api-and-axios-with-hooks-useeffect-and-usestate-85d6bd7357c2)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [Video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) HTML element.  `ReactPlayer` didn't work because I couldn't get the thumbnail to show correctly. (`poster` attribute works perfectly).

Example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Video extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className='player-wrapper'>
                <video controls
                    src='/Slam Dunk Contest 2008.mp4'
                    poster='https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28612032/172026551-e5a96748-d724-4a08-b6b3-f44655d4ef39.png'
                    width="820">

                    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos,
                    but don't worry, you can <a href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28612032/172026908-7c33e4cc-ebe5-40de-b9cc-009d12a7ced2.mp4">download it</a>
                    and watch it with your favorite video player!

                </video>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 0):

note that video will show when you build production. develop isn't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).