# How to embed a LOCAL video on a div background in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to embed a LOCAL video on a div background in React but it's not working. In fact, when I embed a URL video, it works, but not from LOCAL file. Is there something special to make this background video work in React?

**Results**

**DO WORK** --> https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

**DO NOT WORK** --> ./assets/videos/show.mp4 (the path is correct)

EDIT:
I inserted controls property and have found out that the video exists, but it plays in blank screen. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.video-container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

.video-container video {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className="video-container">
  <video autoPlay muted loop id="video">
    <source src='https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'} type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Using local video usually isn't the right approach. Why don't you like the working version?

Comment: I think you should place the video in the public folder

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Is there any error in the browser console?  On the network tab of the browser debugging tools, is there a request for the video file?  What is the server’s response?  (There also appears to be an errant closing curly brace in your markup, which implies the possibility of a typo in one of your attempts…)

Comment: I guess not. It should be ok since it's an resource from the own page. I need to get local file. The URL video is just a sample from anywhere.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794257/react-js-react-player-how-to-play-local-video (answer is a copy paste of this thread)

Comment: @David no error in console, no request. Simple video background as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for everyone who tried to help me.

After inserting "controls" for video attribute, I noticed that the video was playing in background, but just BLANK (white video with controls). I followed some instructions from another post to config 'file-loader' for mp4 format. I did, but after the procedure still not worked.

[Webpack 3 locates .mp4 file but video is not playable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645675/webpack-3-locates-mp4-file-but-video-is-not-playable)

Next, I rendered a new video file and then worked. So I can't clearly identify the source of the problem. I guess something happen on the first time I rendered the file, so probably was the VIDEO FORMAT.

For file rendering I used:
Kdenlive for Linux
Video HD 1080p 25 fps
render format: Generic (HD for web) > MP4-H264/AAC

Hope this can give a new approach for those with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a path resolver problem with NodeJS and React compilation. Try to import your video as:

```
import myVideo from './assets/videos/show.mp4';

<div className="video-container">
  <video autoPlay muted loop id="video">
    <source src={myVideo} type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

If this not work, try to put the video inside public folder, this will let the video available after the React compilation.

Comment: Already tried this as well and still not working. By the way, video on public folder pops an error: Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/assets/videos/show.mp4 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: as far as I remember, if you store content in your public folder - you will need to use it as a URL and not an import. eg `yourAppUrl/path/to/video`. Some more info here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: The module not found error is because your react (webpack) is not prepared to handle an mp4 video. Try this solution that adds the webpack loader to react: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465127/how-to-load-a-local-video-in-react-using-webpack